# How to use the data received from PHP with jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery

My question is related to the data being received from the Php file. Firstly I will post the code below so you have a clearer picture.

```
$(function(){
$(".test").click(function(){

var name =$(this).attr('name');
var info = 'test=' + name;
var div= name;
var its= $(this);

    $.ajax({  
     type: "GET",  
     url: "test.php",  
     data: info,  
     success: 

  function(data)

  {  

    its.closest('.a_cont').find('.cont6R').html(data)}  


               });        

     });
           });
```

Ok I am performing a check in the php file (if the mysql_num_rows is == 1) if this is True I want to slideDown a div with Jquery. What I dont understand how will I tell jquery that the if statement is true and it should slide the div down. I hope I am making some sense and lastly could some one tell me the data I am currently receiving is due to the echo function in php can I receive data If I dont echo also? Please kindly post an example how this all works so I can learn from it cheers much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

php file

```
<?php
...
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
        echo 'ok';
        else
        echo 'error';
...
?>
```

js file

```
$(function(){
$(".test").click(function(){

var name =$(this).attr('name');
var info = 'test=' + name;
var div= name;
var its= $(this);

    $.ajax({  
     type: "GET",  
     url: "test.php",  
     data: info,  
     success: 

  function(data)

  {  

if(data == 'ok')
$('#myDiv').slideDown(500)
else
return false;


               });        

     });
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

"data" in your success function is what ever the php file echos out. So you need to check in your success function for the result you want.

e.g.

$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "test.php",
     data: info,
     success:

```
function(data)
{
  if(data=='success')
  {
      //slide down div with animate();
  }  
     else
  {
     // do something else like show an error message
  }
}});
```

So with that handler, if your test.php file didn't return 'success' it would do whatever your else command did.